# Pathauto taxonomy terms in content paths

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I'm using pathauto and want to set it up so that when a new page is created (which has the taxonomy field) it will add the taxonomy terms into the url. For example, if I have the following vocabulary:

- Page Categories

  - About
  - Articles

When I create a page called 'My Page', and select 'About' as the taxonomical term, I would like the url to be http://example.com/about/my-page.

I've messed around with the URL Aliases settings page but 'Taxonomy term paths' does not apply to Basic pages.

I've looked everywhere for this and I'm going crazy.

Comment: Hello @Frankie, and welcome to _Drupal Answers_. I added the tag for the Drupal version; if you are asking for Drupal 7, then let me know it, and I will change the tag (or you can change it).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking under the wrong section. You want to look at 'node paths' in the path auto settings. Under that section you need to put '/[term-raw]/[title-raw]' for content of type 'Page'.

Install token module as well

Comment: Found the answer!

Apply the patch found here:

http://drupal.org/node/741914

Comment: when you say "node paths" do you mean "Content Paths"? I have Content, Taxonomy and User Paths under URL-Aliases... Also... I tried to commit the patch and failed.

Comment: In D6 it's called 'node paths'. For you 'Content Paths" looks like the right one