# Pathauto taxonomy term alias for content paths

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I am trying to make my nodes URL aliases use taxonomy term aliases through [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto), but I cant seem to figure it out if there is an alternative.

For example, I am trying to use questions/[term:url:alias]/[node:title], but I am getting an error because taxonomies are not in content patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pathauto taxonomy terms in content paths](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/pathauto-taxonomy-terms-in-content-paths)
there is a comment to the answer on this post that links to a drupal.org issue.

http://drupal.org/node/741914#comment-3714746
This is a patch for Token. It seems to be for an older version than the latest beta I've got installed... So I had to hand apply the patch to token.tokens.inc "by hand".

It gave me taxonomy for content paths. stuff like [node:term], [node:term:tid], [node:Term:vocabulary], etc.

I don't have files in front of me atm but I will post the token.tokens.inc later if need be. (would post the text, but it's more than the limit for a post here)

[Token.tokens.inc](http://wernercd.is-a-geek.com/node/1) - 7.x-1.0-beta

Comment: yes please do i tried doing it by hand and wasnt really sure how to and patching it is giving me a error, i appreciate it, thank you

Comment: I've done similar things before so it wasn't terribly difficult... basically the file is a diff file... it describes WHERE changes happen and the +'s are lines to add, - are lines to remove. I'll put up the token.tokens.inc shortly. HOPEFULLY beta2 or a release version will include this as I see *A LOT* of questions here about Node/Token/Taxonomy.

Comment: I'm setting up a second site with it atm... and I broke something else lol. As soon as I get it up and verify it's working I'll post the inc.

Comment: Lol ok ill be on the look out for it, thanks again I appreciate it

Comment: i tried using your patch at the top but its not working correctly or something, and it gave me a white screen when i tried to go to my config section

Comment: I've got it working on two sites... let me see if I can replace the file as an actual text file.

Comment: awesome :) Yeah... I just got a major part of what I was trying to get working working. Tokens, Views and relationships OH MY. Also made a couple minor type corrections on the [node:terms]. Sleep is good.

Comment: lol yeah tell me about it, glad to hear you have everything working, thank you again for helping

Comment: I wouldn't say everything is working... by far. Throw an accepted, a vote up and god speed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [Entity Translation Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) and [Title module](https://www.drupal.org/project/title)

Once you have the above modules configured you should have an option to include translated token for all the entities.